# Assigning names in a list using variables?

Tags: r, list

If I have a variable such as `name.string <- "name"`, how can I use that to assign the name of a value in a list to return something like

```
$name
  [1] "value"
```

Using `list(name.string = "value")` returns `$name.string [1] value`.

And for reasons I can't seem to figure out, `list(get("name.string") = "value")` returns

`Error: unexpected '=' in "list(get("name.string") ="`.

Obviously, I'm not interested in the manual solution (write "name" in the assignment) since this is being replicated for thousands of rows.

Comment: `mylist <- list(name = "oldvalue"); mylist[[name.string]] <- "value"` Is that what you're after?

Comment: @Frank - it's the inverse situation, where I want to create a new key with that key name. Matthew's answer gets at that.

Comment: Okay. I think `mylist <- list(); mylist[[name.string]] <- "value"; mylist[[name.string2]] <- "value2"` should do that. You can try it out to see, or look at `help("[[")`

Comment: Perfect @Frank. That's exactly what I wanted (and I feel like a dolt for not thinking of it). If you submit an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access and assign by number or name using double brackets:

```
mylist                 <- list()
name.string            <- "name"
name.string2           <- "name2"
value                  <- "hello"
value2                 <- "world"

mylist[[name.string]]  <- value
mylist[[name.string2]] <- value2

# an alternative to the previous line
# that fails to create a name:
mylist[[2]]            <- value2
```

For details on this kind of assignment, see `help("[[<-")`.

As Matthew Plourde said, this dynamically grows your list, so it might be best to preallocate, e.g., with `mylist <- vector("list",2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
structure(list('value'), names=name.string)
```

or

```
l <- list('value')
names(l) <- name.string
```

or even

```
within(list(), assign(name.string, 'value'))
```

But don't use this last one.

Comment: Is it possible to do this recursively? Something like: `my.list <- list(); my.list = c(my.list, name.string = 'value')`. I've been able to do `names(l) <- name.string` if I knew the whole set of names, but I was hoping to learn how to do this recursively.

Comment: I suggest preallocating your list to the desired size, adding each element, and build a name vector at the same time. Then use the second method above to assign all of the names at once.